# inserting variable into table

Tags: php

I am able to generate the activation_key in the following code. But I can't manage to insert it into the table. Blank value gets inserted into the table.
What am I doing wrong? (using PEAR text password and other extensions)

```
                $activation_key = Text_Password::createFromLogin($data['email'], 'rot13');
                $sql = "INSERT INTO auth (firstname, lastname,gender,dob,mobileno,landlineno,addressline1,addressline2,addressline3,country,state,city,pincode,email,username,password,question,answer,activation_key)
                VALUES ('" . $db->escapeSimple($data['firstname']) . "','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['lastname'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['gender'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['dob'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['mobileno'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['landlineno'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['address1'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['address2'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['address3'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['country'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['state'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['city'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['pin'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['email'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['username'])."','"
                                    . md5($db->escapeSimple($data['pwd']))."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['question'])."','"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['answer']). "', '"
                                    . $db->escapeSimple($data['activiation_key'])."')";
          $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value thats inside the VALUES(...) part of the query?

Comment: activation_key variable is getting generated. Because I am getting an email with that code. The problem is with the sql query.

Comment: All other columns except activation_key are correctly added.

Comment: You mispelled the variable name in the last line of the insert. Are you using any ide?

Comment: by the way, you generate the $activation_key in the first line, but insert $data['activation_key'] in the last line

Comment: I corrected the spelling and still not able to insert the key in the table. I am not using any ide. Using vi. What will you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data['$activiation_key']` doesn't actually appear to hold `$activation_key`

plus if you really cut and paste then `$activiation_key` is spelt wrongly

Comment: Thanks. 1) corrected the spelling
2) Changed the line to something like this... .$db->escapeSimple($activation_key)."')";
And it solved the problem. Is it ok to use vi or should I use something else to improve my coding time?

Comment: nothing wrong w/ vi - i used that for years and years, for php coding these days i tend to use eclipse, and notepad++ on Windows